# How long should I wait for my gas oven to heat up?

Tags: oven

My cheap rental apartment comes with a (presumably cheap) gas oven. Although this oven has a temperature control, it lacks any sort of indicator to tell me when it has reached the desired temperature. I have reason to believe this oven is relatively new, but I do not know the model or brand.

Understanding that every oven is different, what is the *longest* reasonable amount of time I should wait when preheating my oven for 300, 350, 400, and 500 degrees?

Comment: Do you have an oven thermometer?

Comment: @Catija No, I do not.

Comment: I believe you but that is odd you have no indication it is at the set temperature.

Comment: Old gas ovens without fancy electronics generally don't, other than you noticing the flame cycling as mentioned in my comment below.

Comment: Can you hear the gas turn on and off? Once it turns off that means the oven's thermostat thinks the oven has reached temperature. (As others point out, it's worth getting an oven thermometer to verify the thermostat is accurate).

Comment: If you have a knob to set your temperature, it may click when you turn it if it is preheated to the right temperature.  Its weird, but this is how all the gas ovens I've ever used have been.  I'm in the US, though, so ymmv depending on where you are.  To check if this is the case, set your oven for 200 or so, give it about 20 minutes (should be plenty of time to get up to a temp that low), then twist the knob back and forth.  If you hear a faint, mechanical "click" then you know your oven is preheated.  Be sure to reset the knob to the correct temperature!

Comment: To be clear, the way this oven works is that as you turn the knob to a higher temperature, a gas flame beneath the oven (visible at the right angle through a set of small holes) gets larger or smaller. Same as when when you turn a gas stove up and down, except this knob has numeric temperature labels. As far as I can tell, the oven has no built-in thermostat whatsoever. Since asking this question, I have bought an oven thermometer, and the dial is... kind of accurate, sometimes. It's enough for the very simple things I bake, like chocolate chip cookies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wait until it's hot... if it doesn't have a built-in indicator, buy an inexpensive oven thermometer - they can either sit on a shelf or hang from one, usually. And see when it gets to the right temperature.

If you're dealing with an old and inexpensive oven, it may be miscalibrated anyway, so you'll want the thermometer to tell you if setting it to 350F **is actually making it** 350F in the first place... this will allow you to adjust if necessary (may need to adjust either up or down, depending).

How long it takes will depend on the oven's efficiency and how well it's insulated, so it's impossible for us to guess. It could be anything from 5 to 30 minutes, which is why the thermometer is necessary.

If you don't want to buy a thermometer (though I **strongly** suggest that you do), I'd wait at least 20 minutes. There's nothing wrong with leaving your oven preheating "too" long.

Comment: And if you're *really* unlucky and your oven is taking longer than this to heat up you'll discover it once enough things come out underbaked (or take way longer than expected). I don't know how likely it is with gas, but I've seen an electric oven that could take I think at least 40 minutes for higher temperatures, and on top of that, would beep to indicate it was ready when it was still under temperature. So you're *probably* fine with ~20 minutes, but pretty much anything's possible.

Comment: It could also not be installed properly.  For example gas line too small.

Comment: Depending on the oven, you may be able to tell (by sight or sound, observing closely the first time so you know what to look or listen for after that) when the gas goes from "full on" to Pilot. If it does that once or twice, it thinks it's at temperature and maintaining, rather than heating. But you still want the thermometer, which is an inexpensive but near-essential item for using an oven, especially a "cheap" one. With experience you may find it less essential, but you have to get to that point first, and it's still a good check.